# What will happen if I install the same package twice, for example the ubuntu-desktop?

Tags: apt, gui

So I was wondering, what would happen if I run the command

```
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

and then it failed to install a few packages, so I just did the following

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

where I'm installing again for the few packages remaining.

Will this create any unwanted results?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

No harm will come.

The second time you try to install a package it will simply tell you it's already installed.

If the package was just installed it will say:

```
<Package> is already the newest version (<version number>)
```

If the package was upgraded since it was last installed/upgraded then it will be upgraded:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  <Package>
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, ___ to remove and ___ not upgraded
```